# Перенос БД в оперативную память, находящуюся в docker контейнере

Tags: postgresql, docker

Есть docker контейнер, в нем стоит Postgress. Все это используется для тестов и работает очень медленно. Можно ли затюнить БД так, чтобы она полностью находилась в памяти и не помешает ли контейнер этому?

Comment: Это [выполнимо](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7872693/2076787). Хотя на вид весьма причудливо, т. к. встроенного в постгрес решения нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете просто создать ram-диск в системе и хранить данные на нем, постгрес даже не заметит подвоха:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
docker run -d -v /mnt/ramdisk:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

На моей машине успешно запустилось и создало таблицу через generate_series.

NB: этот метод не стоит применять для постоянного хранилища из-за высоких рисков потерять данные.

Comment: По ссылке выше пишут, что как только рамдиск существующего инстанса будет пересоздан, постгрес откажется стартовать, т. к. кластер БД окажется повреждён. Для одноразовых докер-контейнеров, которые удаляются после остановки, это ок. Стоит отметить эту деталь в ответе.

Comment: @D-side тут вроде и так весь контекст об этом говорит. Добавил.

Comment: Я про то, что если контейнер с такой БД остановить и запустить обратно, он **может не стартануть**. То, что данные улетят вникуда, и так понятно.